# When I use the © symbol it displays Â© instead

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to add the `© All rights reserved` text in my footer. I've done that but when I physically put the `©` in the `index.html` file it displays this instead `Â© All rights reserved`.

I'm not putting the `Â` symbol myself. It auto generates it on the website. In the file itself, it does not exist. It doesn't even exist when I do view-source. How can I fix this issue?

Comment: https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/a/29683/90295

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Click the "Run code snippet" button to check output.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<style>
body {
    font-size: 20px;
}
</style>
<body>

<p>I will display &#169;</p>
<p>I will display &#xA9;</p>
<p>I will display &copy;</p>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: This fixed it! But I can't put this as the answer for some reason. I have to wait a minute

Comment: is `&copy;` supported by the standard? AFAIK, it's not...?

Answer (score 1):

Inorder to incorporate the copyright symbol, you can use © in your code
try this -

```
&copy; All rights reserved
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this to the HTML head. This issue is related to character encoding

```
<head>
...
<meta charset="utf-8">
...
</head>
```

Comment: While this code snippet may be the solution, [including an explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-%E2%80%8C%E2%80%8Bcode-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.